# Convert Disparity Map to DSM (Digital Surface Model)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I have two images, I have found the Disparity Map. How I should convert the disparity map to DSM?

I am a MATLAB user. Kindly tell me what i need to do further.